# Hide files in dual boot:

Tags: dual-boot, 15.10, autohide

I have windows and ubuntu in the same system. I have hidden some files in the windows, but those files become visible when I use Ubuntu 15.10.
How can I hide those files in both the OS?

Comment: Could you be more specific on the files that you want hide?

Comment: I want to hide one or more entire folder(s) containing some softwares/games/movies/videos, etc.

Comment: In my oppinion, you can't. Because linux 'hide' its folder or files using the dot '.' on the beginning of it's folder or file. While Windows hide their folder and files with different method.

Answer (score 0):

Encypting your folder is the best way for you to hide.

Encrypting folders and files is a way to protect them from unwanted access. Encrypting File System (EFS) is a feature of Windows that you can use to store information on your hard disk in an encrypted format. Encryption is the strongest protection that Windows provides to help you keep your information secure.

To do it (on windows):

1.Right-click the folder or file you want to encrypt, and then click **Properties**.

2.Click the **General** tab, and then click **Advanced**.

3.Select the **Encrypt contents to secure data** check box, click OK, and then click OK again.

[Source](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/encrypt-decrypt-folder-file#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: But won't it hide the folder permanently for the ubuntu?  Is it possible to hide/unhide the folder anytime in the ubuntu?

Comment: @RD017: You can decrypt it by unchecking **Encrypt contents to secure data** check box